# Detection of language in the GitHub repository

Tags: java, git, github, repository

I create a project in Java in the Spring framework, where I also have many HTML pages (39.4%).

[image: languages bar]

```
Java 45.3%   
HTML 39.4%   
JavaScript 11.2%     
CSS 4.1%
```

The point is that this is a Java project and I'll be doing code refactoring and probably the percentage of Java will be lower than the percentage of HTML. I am afraid that then the project language will be changed to HTML at this point:

[image: main language in repository list]

If there is more HTML code, will the project language change from Java to HTML?

If so, what do you need to do to set Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can [override Linguist's default behaviour using `.gitattributes`](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides). It is possible to

- change the detected language of a file, e.g. telling GitHub that your HTML files should be classified as Java (this probably isn't appropriate), or
- classify your HTML as documentation, generated files, or vendor data; each of these classifications should prevent your HTML from being considered in GitHub's language statistics.

Without knowing more about what those files represent I can't make a more concrete recommendation.